# Cannot enter/Submit with Selenium python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The enter/return/sumbit form does not seem to work - I really dont understand why.

The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

import pandas as pd
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://tjekditnet.dk/')

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[38]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]").click()

time.sleep(1)



Search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/fieldset/input")

Search.clear()

Search.send_keys("Nørrebrogade 1 2200")

**enter/return/submit**

time.sleep(3)
```

I'm fairly new to this, so feel free to call me a newbie :)

Thanks in advance!

I have tried with:

- `Search.submit()` --> To submit an element, it must be nested inside a form element
- `Search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` --> Nothings happens, no error code
- `Search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` --> Nothings happens, no error code

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace?

Comment: For https://tjekditnet.dk/ I get 401 Unauthorized, the xpath with div[38] is too complex (if the page ever changes slightly - then it's broken), if I could see the html I'm sure I could find a simple css selector

Comment: Another user commented on this - perhaps the site is region locked? xd
The problem is that I get absolutely zero errors.. 
Everything works as intended, besides the "Enter" press.

Comment: Does the Enter press work when you use the website manually? Webdriver mimics the keyboard and mouse perfectly, so if you can do it manually you can automate it

Comment: It does work with Enter press on the site yes :D

Comment: Search.send_keys("Nørrebrogade 1 2200" + Keys.ENTER) is how I write that stuff

Comment: and if it's being fussy, then click into first before send keys

Comment: I tried the excact variant you just used and still get the same error/no result :(
I also tried with RETURN instead.. My brain is exploding soon haha - do you think it could be site related?

Comment: In Chrome, right-click Inspect > Elements > Ctrl + F, paste in the xpath and see if the element is found

Comment: I tried copying a CLASS instead of the ID that relates to the same input field, but it has the exact same XPATH :D
My sole problem seems to be with the "Enter" feature for god knows what reason haha

Comment: ok, that's all the ideas that I have, remember webdriver will work on the 1st element found

Comment: I understand if you are out of ideas - so am I XD 
Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the page wasn't loading fast enough.
Although I had multiple sleep timers, I didn't give it time to load the address before hitting "enter".

So to fix it:
Search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/fieldset/input")

Search.clear()

Search.send_keys("Nørrebrogade 1, 2200 København N")

time.sleep(2)

Search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

---

A huge thanks to @Syehoon Kim and @Gords <3